# Can you use parent function variables inside a returned function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Here's the function code:

```js
function TestFunction(number){
  return function(e){
    return `${number}`;
  }
}
```

When I use it on google's devtools command line it returns:

```
function(e){
  return `${number}`;
}
```

So it looks like the function returned is not created with the number I give to TestFunction, instead it takes the string just like it was written. I have tried to use concatenation instead of interpolation but still not working. What can I do?

Comment: The value of `number` is resolved when the function is actually executed.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, thank you I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a **closure** around the second function, so it will have memory of what `num` is.

```js
function a(num) {
  return function b() {
    return `${num}`;
  }
}

const c = a(6);

console.log(c());
```